# Trouble in linking the libIEC61850 library with GTK3+ for C

Tags: c, makefile, gtk, gtk3

I'm having trouble combining compilations and linkages for two separate libraries. Following is a makefile for one of the libraries (libIEC61850):

```
LIBIEC_HOME=../../iec61850/libiec61850-1.4.0/
#Add this somehow:
#cc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` main.c -o a.out `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`

PROJECT_BINARY_NAME = a.out
PROJECT_SOURCES += main.c
INCLUDES += -I.

include $(LIBIEC_HOME)/make/target_system.mk
include $(LIBIEC_HOME)/make/stack_includes.mk

all:    $(PROJECT_BINARY_NAME)

include $(LIBIEC_HOME)/make/common_targets.mk

$(PROJECT_BINARY_NAME): $(PROJECT_SOURCES) $(LIB_NAME)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(PROJECT_BINARY_NAME) $(PROJECT_SOURCES) $(INCLUDES) $(LIB_NAME) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROJECT_BINARY_NAME)
```

I would like to add the gtk-3.0 library in the compilation of main.c. To execute a typical gtk3 function, I simply write:

```
$ cc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` main.c -o a.out `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

and the executable is generated without problem. How can I combine these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Following is a Makefile to combine the libIEC61850 and GTK+ 3.0 libraries:

```
# Makefile to combine the libIEC61850 and GTK+-3.0 Libraries
# path to libIEC61850:
LIBIEC_HOME=../../iec61850/libiec61850-1.4.0/

#Add this somehow:
#cc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` main.c -o a.out `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`

PROJECT_BINARY_NAME = a.out
PROJECT_SOURCES += main.c

include $(LIBIEC_HOME)/make/target_system.mk
include $(LIBIEC_HOME)/make/stack_includes.mk

all:    $(PROJECT_BINARY_NAME)

include $(LIBIEC_HOME)/make/common_targets.mk

$(PROJECT_BINARY_NAME): $(PROJECT_SOURCES) $(LIB_NAME)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(shell pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) $(LDFLAGS) \
        -o $(PROJECT_BINARY_NAME) $(PROJECT_SOURCES) $(INCLUDES) \
        $(LIB_NAME) $(LDLIBS) $(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)

clean:
        rm -f $(PROJECT_BINARY_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` to CFLAGS and `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` to LDLIBS:

```
CFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)
LDLIBS += $(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)
```

They'll be sucked into the build commands the way you want, assuming all recipes follow conventional variable naming.

Use [target specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) if passing the flags to everything isn't to your liking.

Comment: Adding these causes all the GTK functions to raise 'undefined reference to' errors. I tried fixing this using the `-c` flag, but then I get the following error: `gcc: warning: ../../iec61850/libiec61850-1.4.0//build/libiec61850.a: linker input file unused because linking not done`.

Comment: Sounds like LDLIBS isn't doing it's job. Which target is getting the 'undefined reference' and what does it's recipe look like? Tried putting it after the include?

Comment: @SteinnHauser forgot the tag.

Comment: All the GTK functions are listed as undefined references (i.e. `gtk_entry_get_type`, `gtk_init` and so on). Can't seem to find the source files as `apt-get source libgtk-3-dev` returns a `E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list ` error. Tried to link using -L to the headers but this didn't work either

Comment: @SteinnHauser Any chance you can upload a repository for me to look at? The "references" should come from the `$(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)`. Does the output of that command appear in the build invocation?

Comment: Whipped up a quick repository for the main and make files:
https://github.com/steinnhauser/IEC61850_GTK/tree/master
The library which the makefile refers to is the following libIEC61850 library:
https://github.com/mz-automation/libiec61850/

Comment: @SteinnHauser I will check it out later!